# Django / Anaconda - Can not start server

Tags: python, django, anaconda

I made a new django project on a different machine (PC) in a conda enviroment. Now I copied the django project folder and created a new enviroment on the new PC with conda. I installed everything like on the "old" machine but however if I type `python manage.py runserver` it throws a message:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txVRc.jpg)

Does someone know if something is missing or what can I do to run the django project on the new pc?

I have latest conda version 4.8.4, django version 3.0.3

Comment: Please copy and paste the error message instead linking an image.

Comment: You need to make migrations first. `python manage.py makemigrations` then `python manage.py migrate` and finally `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Migration 0005 that's referred to in that error has an "ä" in the name of the migration, so it's expecting an "ä" in the filename. Does your new PC support filenames with "ä" in them? (Some might not, if they've been set up expecting everything to be in English only.)

Comment: When you are showing some code or sharing a error message, don't send themself instead of screenshot. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you can see how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you make and migrate your migrations they have dependencies on other on other migration files. So, a migration with a dependency to the file in your error message cannot find that migrations file. This has likely happened while copying the project, maybe the file did not copy. If this is a development environment a quick fix would be to delete your local db file, as well as the migrations folder and then re-run makemigrations and migrate.

This could also be a multi app problem where you have a migration dependency to another app, and have not ran the migrations for said app.

[django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937343/django-db-migrations-exceptions-nodenotfounderror)

[Django NodeNotFoundError during migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281377/django-nodenotfounderror-during-migration)